# what is the difference between using "--stdout" and not using it in gzip?

Tags: unix, gzip

The below is the code that makes me curious about `--stdout` of the `gzip`. Using the `diff` command on the outputs from two different commands tells me the two files are different, but the manual check says otherwise. What's going on?

```
$echo "test" > tmpx
$cat tmpx | gzip > tmpx1.gz
$cat tmpx | gzip --stdout > tmpx2.gz

$diff tmpx1.gz tmpx2.gz
Binary files tmpx1.gz and tmpx2.gz differ

$zcat tmpx1.gz
test

$zcat tmpx2.gz
test

$cat tmpx1.gz
a▒U+I-.▒▒5▒; 

$cat tmpx2.gz
?▒U+I-.▒▒5▒;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Terrence's correct answer, there is no difference, *period*.  When you pipe input to gzip, it automatically sends its output to stdout, whether or not you specify `--stdout`.

As Terrence noted, the difference is simply in the time stamp.  If you did `cat tmpx | gzip > tmpx1.gz` followed by `cat tmpx | gzip > tmpx2.gz` at least two seconds later, then you would see that the resulting files will differ due to the time stamp.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the compressed data.

What you are seeing is a difference in bytes 4-8 of the file. This contains a unix timestamp of when the gzip file was created.